# xor after applying filters on an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, filter, series, xor

We have an original array and a list of filters where each filter consists of indices which are allowed through the filter. The filters are rather nice, e.g. they are grouped for each power of 2 in the following way (the filters are upto n = 20).

- `1 (2^0) = 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19`
- `2 (2^1) = 1 2 5 6 9 10 13 14 17 18`
- `4 (2^2) = 1 2 3 4 9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20`
- `8 (2^3) = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 17 18 19 20`

I hope you get the idea. Now we would apply some or all of these filters (user dictates which filters to apply) to the original array and the xor of the elements of the transformed array is the answer. To take an example if the original array would have been `[3 7 8 1 2 9 6 4 11]` e.g. n = 9 and we needed to apply the filters of 4, 2 and 1, the transformations would be like this.

- After applying filter of 4 - `[3 7 8 1 x x x x 11]`
- After applying filter of 2 - `[3 7 x x x x x x 11]`
- After applying filter of 1 - `[3 x x x x x x x 11]`

Now the xor of 3 and 11 e.g. 8 is the answer. I can solve this O(n * no. of filters) time, but I need a better solution which might give the answer in O(no of filters) time. Is there any way to take advantage of the properties of xor and/or pre-compute the results for some and then give the answer for the filters. This is because there are many queries with filters, so I need to answer the queries in O(no of filters) time. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It can be done in O(M) where M is the number of items that pass all filters (independent of the number of filters), is that OK?

Comment: I would like to know that solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in O(M) where M is the number of items that pass all filters (independent of the number of filters) by iterating over the array in a particular way, generating only the indexes that pass all the filters.

This is easier to see if you write down the examples starting at zero:

- 1: `0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18` (numbers that don't contain 1)
- 2: `0 1 4 5 8 9 12 13 16 17` (numbers that don't contain 2, etc)
- 4: `0 1 2 3 8 9 10 11 16 17 18 19`
- 8: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 16 17 18 19`

The filters are really just a constraint on the bits of the indexes in the array. That constraint is of the form `index & filters = 0`, where `filters` is just the sum of all the individual filters (eg 1 + 2 + 4 = 7). Given a valid index `i` the next valid index `i'` can be computed with only primitive operations: `i' = (i | filters) + 1 & ~filters`. The idea here is to set the bits that are filtered to zero so the +1 will carry through them, then filtered bits are cleared again to make the index valid. The total effect is that the unfiltered bits are incremented and the filtered bits stay zero.

This gives a simple algorithm to iterate directly over all valid indexes. Start at 0 (which is always valid) and increment using the rule above until the end of the array is reached:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i = (i | filters) + 1 & ~filters)
    // do something with array[i], like XOR them all together
```